# PHP get object from JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, twitter, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the text from twitter using php and JSON data. I used this script

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("twitter/twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library you downloaded in step 3

$twitteruser = "user"; //user name you want to reference
$notweets = 5; //how many tweets you want to retrieve
$consumerkey = "XXXXXXXXX"; //Noted keys from step 2
$consumersecret = "XXXXXXXXX"; //Noted keys from step 2
$accesstoken = "XXXXXXXX"; //Noted keys from step 2
$accesstokensecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"; //Noted keys from step 2

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

$json = json_encode($tweets, true);

echo $json;

?>
```

When I do so it echos all the json data like `[{"created_at":"Wed Apr 01 21:34:33 +0000 2015","id":5.8338196298063e+17,"id_str":"583381962980626432","text":"THIS IS A TWEET",ECT`

All I want it to echo is the text in the `"text"` object (THIS IS A TWEET). I have tried adding:

`foreach($json as $i){
    echo $i['text'];
}`

But get an error. Any thoughts?

Here is the full JSON [image: JSON]

Comment: What error you get ? Can you please show full your json output ?

Comment: what is $tweets before you json_encode it? it looks like you just need to `json_decode` your result into a normal array

Comment: the error is ` Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ` . If I dont encode it and echo it it just output `array`

Comment: try to `var_dump` in here `foreach($json as $i){
    var_dump($i);
}` what is the result ?

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam same thing, invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: try to `echo $json[0]['text']` or `echo $json[0]->text` after you `json_encode` it

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam `Cannot use string offset as an array in`

Comment: `echo $json[0]->text` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75342/discussion-between-packy-and-eko-junaidi-salam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `for()` loop and inside you can access to text with `$tweets[$i]->text`

Try with this:

```
<?php

    for($i = 0; $i < count($tweets); $i++) {
    echo $tweets[$i]->text . "<br>";
    }        
?>
```

Output:

```
THIS IS A TWEET
ANOTHER TWEET
```

Comment: I get `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: I added an image of the full JSON output in the consol

Comment: @Packy edit your question with the out put of echo $tweets; and let me know

Comment: $tweets just gives me `array`

Comment: @Packy edit with print_r($tweets) because is you see array then $tweets is not a json

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to echo the data AFTER you have encoded it.  Instead of $json, use $tweets.

```
foreach($tweets as $i) {
    echo $i['text']
}
```

If you want the tweets echoed as a json encoded array, then store it into a new array and encode that:

```
$data = array();
foreach($tweets as $i)
    array_push($data, $i['text']);

$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I get the error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in`